# setVisibility not working

Tags: android, button, visibility

I am trying to hide a button if a logged in user is a Donor. I have my code like this.

```
String typ = user.get("type").toString();
    Log.d("before checking type", typ);

    if (typ == "Donor"){

        ne.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //ne.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

In the log, I get the result `Donor`, so I know the call to the database is working. But the button I need to hide, doesn't hide. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
if (typ.equals("Donor"))
```